# How does Angular's bypassSecurityTrustHtml pipe work under the hood?

Tags: angular

I've used variations of `SafeHtml` pipe, but I'm wondering how it actually works under the hood. How does Angular know that the text being applied to the DOM has been passed through a pipe and is safe? Is it simply done at the compilation stage or is it a run-time check?

The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) says:

> Calling any of the bypassSecurityTrust... APIs disables Angular's
>   built-in sanitization for the value passed in

Common implementation of a safe HTML pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'sanitizeHtml'})
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
  }
  transform(v:string):SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
  }
}
```

**Update:** Figured it out from the [dom_sanitization_service.ts source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.ts). The `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` function returns a `new SafeHtmlImpl(value);` instance. During the `sanitize` process, there is a check: `if (value instanceof SafeHtmlImpl)`, and if so, the sanitization process is skipped

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding the point of the function.
It doesn't actually sanitize, it doesn't even check the HTML.
All it does is create an object which has a flag set so the Angular security won't block it. If the string has unsafe HTML, it won't be blocked.

The developer is still supposed to write some function themselves or use some other tool to make sure that the HTML is safe.

Comment: Didn't mean any offense by it, yeah it's possible I didn't get what you were asking. I did still answer you by saying that Angular wraps the string in an object (`SafeHtml`).